# How can i change the Record separator for sed

Tags: linux, sed

I know that i can chnage the `RS =something` in awk.

Is there any way i can change the `\n` RS to something for muliline pattern in sed

Comment: The sentence "Is there any way i can change the `\n` RS to something for muliline pattern in sed" is confusing." Would you mind editing it to make it clearer? Also, an example of input and the output you want would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: no, you can't. Sed reads lines of text, not records with fields.

Depending on the nature of your text, you could use `tr` to first change all `\n`s to an unused character and your desired (single-character) record separator to `\n`. Make the changes you want in `sed`, then use `tr` to change the separators back.

You could also manipulate the hold space to let you work with multiple lines of text. This is described in, for example, *sed & awk* by Dougherty and Robbins.

It's probably easier just to use `awk`, though.

Answer (score 1):

GNU sed has the option [`-z` / `--null-data` / `--zero-terminated`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-_002dz) for null separated records, but that's about as good as it gets.

Example:

```sh
sed -z 's/\n\n+/\n\n/g'
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you want to replace all the new line characters using sed?
Then do this. If not explain what do you want

```
 sed -e :a -e N -e 's/\n/|/g' -e '$!ba' file
```